# Pwm settings of a Sg90 servo motor

Tags: robotic-arm, servomotor, rcservo

I use a TowerPro sg90.

1.5 ms for the centre position 0 degree, and 2 ms pulse for +90 degree and -90 degree with a 1ms pulse.

But it's definitely not looking like it goes for 90 degree or -90 degree.

I did read, some said "I tested two of them for about 130.000 cycles, without load, at one cyle per second, and 70 degrees travel." .

What does that mean "130.000 cycles at one cycle per second"?

Comment: it means exactly what it says ..... which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

They use "cycle" to mean moved left then right.

They moved it left then right 130,000 times. They did it at a rate of once per second. They moved it 70 degrees, without any load attached.